# I have column with value (200ML) and I need to separate the (ML) from the column

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have column with value (200ML) and  I need to separate the (ML) from the column !

Comment: Ok, what the code you have already tried and what was wrong with it?

Comment: This is a bad design.  You should separate values from their units.  Two columns, not one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you want the leading numeric portion and the trailing alpha portion of the string '200ML' to be returned as separate columns. If that's correct you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to do this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEXT_STRING, '^[0-9]+', 1, 1) AS LEAD_NUMERIC,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEXT_STRING, '[A-Za-z]+$', 1, 1) AS TRAILING_ALPHA
  FROM TABLE_A
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=94ec1c66b6bffc7bab64fa916fb7ac7a)